# how to set the focus on a external windows I created?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

In my background.js, I use that to open a new external popup window

```
chrome.windows.create({type:"panel", url: "https://www.example.com/", width:320, height:240},
 function (_win) {
    win = _win.id;
});
```

How can I set the focus back later on this popup window ?

Comment: I'm going to go ahead and answer this before wOxxOm or Xan wake up. Use [windows.update](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/windows#method-update) like this: 'chrome.windows.update(win, {focused: true});' where win is the windowId you stored when you created the panel.

Comment: @CViejo, :-D make that an answer, if there was no duplicate question (I don't see one).

Comment: @CViejo Haha. However, **do not answer questions in comments**. Don't you want that juicy, juicy reputation from upvotes _when wOxxOm or Xan wake up_?

Answer (score 1):

Use [chrome.windows.update](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/windows#method-update):

```
chrome.windows.update(windowId, {focused: true});
```